# Eliminate decimal strings displaying in HTML tables (via poshytip mouseover)

Tags: javascript, jquery, mouseover, d3.js

I have path elements on my page which have an attribute "title" which is an html table of information.  Here is an example:

```
<table>
<tr>
    <td>
        <b><u>California</u></b>
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>
        <u>University</u>
    </td>
    <td>
        <u>Percent</u>
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>
        California 1:
    </td>
    <td>
        6.6%
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>
        California 2:
    </td>
    <td>
        1.2%
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>
        California 3:
    </td>
    <td>
        0.5%
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>
        California 4:
    </td>
    <td>
        10.1%
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>
        California 5:
    </td>
    <td>
        3.6%
    </td>
</tr>
</table>
```

When I initially load the page, the poshytips look fine, but when I update a slider (which updates the tables), some tips get long decimal strings.  The table above is from console.log of the what should be shown upon updating.  However, the value "1.2%" appears as "1.20000000000000002%.  "The values being input are read in from a csv are initially string values with exactly one decimal place. This is how I am updating the tips using d3 (the 'maketip' function just returns the table shown above):

```
state_path.transition()
  .duration(1000)
  .attr('title', function(d) {
    return maketip(d,y);
  })
  .each("end", function(d) {
    var $this = $(this);
    $this.poshytip("update", $this.attr('title') );
  });
```

Is there a way to prevent this, or a way to specify this table as the content for the object?

Comment: Please don't sign your posts. http://stackoverflow.com/faq#signatures

Comment: Can you reproduce the problem in a jsfiddle? Hard to understand what exactly going on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the answer that I found -- thanks for the comments:
Try giving poshytip the function instead of saving it to the title attr.

```
$('.county_path').poshytip({
        content:    function() { 
            return maketip(this.__data__.id, this.__data__.properties.name); 
        },
        className: 'tip-ihme',
        slide:      false,
        followCursor:   true,
        alignTo:    'cursor',
        alignX:     'center'
    });
```